# Using Ubuntu to solve a unique networking problem

Tags: networking, wireguard

Trying to solve an issue with 2 legacy devices that use broadcast to communicate.

Both legacy devices must be on 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.5, not my choosing, something that was coded into the devices years ago.

I'm running two small pc's with 4 NICs each with 22.04 LTS installed, with the internet connected on enp1s0.

Using Wireguard there is a tunnel setup and working between the two small pc's over separate internet connections. I also setup a VXLAN between the two computers after reading that VXLAN can route layer 2 traffic, I know, might not be ideal.

Ultimately, what I want to be able to do is connect my legacy devices on enp4s0 on each of the linux computers and have their broadcast data route over the vxlan\wireguard tunnel.

Below is the Netplan configs of each of the linux computers. I should mention, this is **not** going in a data center, or attached to any production networks.

Am I close on the config? Seems like I might be on the right path, just missing key configs.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
    enp4s0: {}
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces:
        - enp4s0
      addresses: [192.168.0.1/24]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.0.1
      parameters:
        stp: false
        forward-delay: 0
  tunnels:
    wg0:
      mode: wireguard
      port: 51820
      addresses: [10.0.0.1/24]
      peers:
        - public-key: "your_peer_public_key_here"
          allowed-ips: [10.0.0.0/24]
          endpoint: [hostname]:51820
    vxlan0:
      mode: vxlan
      id: 100
      local: 10.0.0.2
      remote: 10.0.0.1
      port: 4789
      link: enp4s0
      addresses: [192.168.0.1/24]
      link: br0
```

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
    enp4s0: {}
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces:
        - enp4s0
      addresses: [192.168.0.5/24]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.0.2
      parameters:
        stp: false
        forward-delay: 0
  tunnels:
    wg0:
      mode: wireguard
      port: 51820
      addresses: [10.0.0.2/24]
      peers:
        - public-key: "your_peer_public_key_here"
          allowed-ips: [10.0.0.0/24]
          endpoint: [hostname]:51820
    vxlan0:
      mode: vxlan
      id: 100
      local: 10.0.0.2
      remote: 10.0.0.1
      port: 4789
      link: enp4s0
      addresses: [192.168.0.5/24]
      link: br0
```

Comment: Please apply the configs and [edit] to state the specific error or problem that is occurring

Comment: @DanielT The configs above are in place. The only part that works correct is the wireguard tunnel. I'm unable to get the 2 devices that I spoke about on the enp4s0 nics to communicate.